# integrate recommendations from facebook into wordpress site

Tags: facebook, wordpress

A client of mine has a recommendations bar on her facebook page that she wants shown in her wordpress sidebar.

I have trawled through the countless number of plugins for this but seem to be using the wrong search words as I keep getting the recommend link (much like the like box).

Is this actually possible - if so any guidance on which plugin to use much appreciated!

(Sorry for the simplicity of my question!!)

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-recommendations-bar/

Answer (score 1):

Try these urls:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendationsbar/

and for sidebar widget:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/

Answer (score 0):

> **useing this**  [facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook/):
>
> [Download](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/facebook.1.4.zip)

using this plugin to display:
    Recommendations Bar,Like Button, send button,follow button,
    comment box, much more functionality using widget to display any where.

> more info to go this url: https://developers.facebook.com/wordpress/